# IOS 16.5 data not sent to GA4 account? Does anyone else have the same issue?

Tags: e-commerce, tracking, google-analytics-4

I'm dealing with revenue data from the back end, and GA4 (web data stream) has a large disparity.

When I looked, I saw that the majority of the missing transactions (those that were sent to back-end data but not GA4) came from

- Device : mobile
- Model : IPhone
- OS version : 16.5

So, has anyone else ever experienced something similar to this problem? and what is the solution?
I would appreciate all your answer. Thankyou!